# Is There A Definitive Source for When Xcode Versions are No Longer Supported by Apple?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm writing up a slideshow on keeping Xcode versions up to date.

It's not difficult to find out when Xcode versions BEGIN support, but not when Apple officially ENDS support.

Maybe the correct answer is "when the next version comes out," but the Xcode version tends to continue working for quite some time after the next variant comes out, and I know some folks that insist on using the old variant until the wheels fall off.

Eventually, the old version will no longer work on the current OS, and we need to hold back the OS to continue running the Xcode variant.

I need to find that point. I call it "The eBay Threshold." That's when we can no longer run the defined variant of Xcode on a new Mac, and need to buy old used Macs to run it.

As you might guess, this is a point of frustration for me. I hates ISO9001, as practiced by some outfits...

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote? It's a perfectly legitimate question for this community. If you don't have an answer (not easy, I know), then just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, Apple stops supporting a version when the next version comes out. "When will it stop working" cannot have a definitive source because there is no firm definition of "working" in the absence of regression testing, and Apple does not regression test old versions of Xcode against new OS X releases.

The requirements are of course contradictory (which I expect you know). It makes some sense to demand near-total reproducibility. In that case, you must never upgrade the OS beyond the point release that existed when the next version of Xcode came out. Upgrading the OS beyond that means running Xcode in an untested mode, using "well, it seems to run" as your only criteria. At the very least, you would need to regression test your own software.

Obviously VMs are the best way to achieve this for a build infrastructure. The VMs need to be very carefully protected from outside traffic since they cannot receive even security updates without breaking their reproducibility.

Of course few develop Mac software this way. (This answer only makes sense for Mac development, and even then assumes that you are not submitting to the App Store. MAS and iOS development must keep up with the latest version of Xcode by Apple policy.)

Comment: Thanks. That's the argument I need to make. It's a long story, and I find it absolutely infuriating. However, it's not as uncommon as you might think. There's a certain mindset, usually rooted in the ISO9001 process, that can easily result in the eBay Threshold.

Comment: Yeah; saying "few develop Mac software this way" is privileged blindness on my part. I've gone through ISO9001 silliness before.